# Doing an iteration of each letter in a string per button click

Tags: javascript

Whenever I press one button, I intend to display a char from a given string. e.g: 1st click => 1st letter , 2nd click => 2nd letter, etc.

This is the code I tried :

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

        function myFunction() {
        var str = "This is a random string";
    for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        var n = str.charAt(i);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n
  };
}
```

Although the iteration runs through the whole string, the unwanted result of the code I have written displays only the last letter when I click the button. What am I missing ?

Comment: Use `innerHTML += n` instead of `innerHTML = n`. Alternatively, why not just do `innerHTML = str`?

Comment: I don't want to be displayed all the string. I just want one letter from string per click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global counter.

```
var counter = 0;
var str = "This is a random string";
document.getElementById("fnc").onclick = myFunction;
function myFunction() {
  var n = str.charAt(counter);
  counter++;
  if (counter == str.length)
    counter = 0;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8r120wo8/).

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `str` , reference to `#demo` outside of `myFunction`

```js
var str = "This is a random string",
  curr = -1,
  demo = document.getElementById("demo");

function myFunction() {
  if (curr < str.length -1) {
    var n = str.charAt(++curr);
    demo.innerHTML += n;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running through the whole string in your click handler. Instead you should create a click handler that that only increments `i` once. Here is one way to do that:

```js
var myFunction = function ( ) {
    var str = "This is a random string";
    var i = 0;

    return function ( ) {
        if ( i < str.length )
            document.getElementById( "demo" ).innerHTML = str[i++];
    };
}( );
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: missing parenthesis around your function

Comment: It works as is, @AndrueAnderson. I added a snippet to verify that.

Comment: "works as is" doesn't mean it's a valid answer, we're trying to promote good coding habits here on Stack Overflow

Comment: You think there is something wrong with this code that a redundant set of parenthesis would fix? This is the only answer that isn't creating variables scoped outside the function that will likely conflict with other code.

Comment: It's also the hardest code to understand for a new developer, which OP clearly is.

Comment: For the record I never said the code was broken, only that it was wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: @Tyler OP didn't say he was trying to understand how it works. If he specifically mentioned that he was trying to learn, that would be a different situation. This code works and will hopefully prevent him from having other issues later. The other answers here could all cause hard to find problems for him later if he defines another variable called `str` or `myString` at some point.

Comment: It was my understanding that the entire purpose of this site is to help people to learn.

Comment: @Tyler We can agree to disagree about that. I use it primarily to learn, but I don't personally think that is the site's entire purpose, or even it's primary purpose.